# PC suddenly crashing randomly with grey stripes on screen (sometimes brown screen)

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure, crash, gpu

While I'm surfing on the internet, playing a game or while watching a video, my computer suddenly freezing and giving me this screen;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RCT9.jpg

And I can't control anything, it doesn't respond any key or any button. Only solution is resetting it from the button on the case.
Sometimes this screen appearing as **brown.**

I don't know which component of my PC (GPU-motherboard-CPU-RAM) is causing this problem and I can't test them one-by-one because I don't have the parts to try out.

It is not connected with GPU or CPU's tempature I recon' because even when they are at 40C°-45C° I am experiencing the same problem.

**Most importantly;** I don't know when this problem will be happen. Because it's not happening while doing or performing a particular
"task" it's just happening randomly. For example last time it happened
when I clicked a youtube link. Before that, it happened while I was staring at desktop.

GPU: ASUS R9 280X
Processor: i7-6700K (not overclocked)
MOBO: ASUS Z-170P
RAM: 2X8GB Corsair 2133Mhz
PSU: Zalman 650Watt 80+
Operation System on SSD

My GPU drivers, OS (W10Pro) and every other drivers always up to date. And this problem is not solved even after I format the PC several times.
Also I unplugged and re-plugged the RAM, GPU, CPU. And I refreshed thermal paste of GPU and CPU's.

Answer (score 0):

Display problems are either a GPU issue or a cable fault. I would suggest removing the GPU and testing it. If the issue still occurs then it's a faulty cable.

Comment: Cable? You mean VGA cable? Because I'm using VGA cable with DVI connector to connect my monitor to GPU

Comment: @user4997999 Yea feels like VGA cable's fault. Swap out the VGA with another one if it still dosen't you can also try changing the DVI connector.